# Tweepy Python Timeline

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to retrive Tweets that particular accounts has posted. I do use 
`user_timeline` parameter from the `tweepy` library, but it includes also replies from the concrete Twitter user. Does anyone has a clue how to omit them?

```
Code:

import tweepy
consumer_key = key
consumer_secret = key
access_key = key
access_secret = key

def get_tweets(username):

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#set count to however many tweets you want; twitter only allows 200 at once
number_of_tweets = 20

#get tweets
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = username,count = number_of_tweets)

#create array of tweet information: username, tweet id, date/time, text
tweets_for_csv = [[username,tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in tweets]

print(str(tweets_for_csv))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `exclude_replies` as a kwarg.

```
tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=number_of_tweets, exclude_replies=True)
```

See [Twitters API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) for a full list of kwargs you can pass.